# flask_restx Swagar is not updating on real time

Tags: flask-restx

I was able to get a List of items (for PUT Operation) which refers to one dictionary after I added one more item on that dictionary(With POST Operation), that new item is not updating on that List to perform the PUT operation on to that New item.
But I confirmed that(with GET Operation), a new item exists in the dictionary.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.